# JavaScript Foundation Reveal Modal Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Working with JavaScripts foundation plugin, reveal (modal). I am trying to get the very basic modal to work, but I don't think I am calling it correctly. In my vendor directory I have copies of `foundation.min.js` and `foundation.reveal.js` and then I am just trying to do work through the first beginner example on the website http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html.

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing Foundation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</a></p>
    <div class="reveal" style="visibility: hidden" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
      <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
      <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
      <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

testing.js

```
$('#exampleModal1').foundation('open');
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong in my setup for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it a bit.  The modal `div` should be inside the same html file as what is calling it.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</a></p>
        <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
          <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
          <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
          <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Go ahead and instantiate Foundation for the entire document.

app.js:

```
$(document).foundation()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed this also and had tried to move the div back into index.html. However, I still could not get the modal to work. I also set the visibility of the div to hidden so that it would actually pop up? Because when I load the page I already see the contents of my div. I edited my question to show you what I mean

Comment: @adamscott Looks like you don't have the foundation.css file linked in which is required for the modal to be hidden and for the modal to work.

Comment: the inline style works alright, but I see what you're saying and I included it now also, but it still is not working

Comment: @adamscott You included it AND removed your inline styling right?  Also, do you have the app.js file linked in that was included with the foundation download?  Should only have `$(document).foundation()` inside of it.

Comment: I did not remove the inline styles until you just mentioned it, but now its gone. I updated my question to include the bit of js I used, but I have not instantiated foundation for the entire document, just the element I'm calling it on. I tried changing it to what you recommended, is there anything else you would try?

Comment: btw I do appreciate the effort you have made to help me here.

Comment: @adamscott No problem man.  I just updated my answer.  Setup your files like the above and it should work fine.  If this doesn't work I'll link you to my Dropbox account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110448/discussion-between-lamelemon-and-adamscott).